# Wamp Password protection is not working - Forbidden error

Tags: apache, security, wamp

I have directory strucutre like this:

```
D:Wamp\WWW\web\Erp\
```

and .htaccess file is reside in above location with this settings

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Site"
AuthUserFile /wamp/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

while my password file reside in Wamp Folder. But i am unable to allow password protection on the particular page. Instead it is showing Prohibited, I know why it is showing prohibited because i am using another .htaccess in main root.

Answer (score 0):

try your WAMP server online using  follow these steps

step 1-: Go to your WAMP server notification icon (in the task bar).

step 2-: Single click on the WAMP server icon.

step 3-: Select last option from the menu, that is, Put Online

step 4-: Your server will restart automatically (in the latest versions only). Otherwise, you have to restart your server manually.